# Laravel: How check if model field is nullable on database

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm set all empty fields to `null` when saving

Using OctoberCMS model event `beforeSave` (equivalent to Laravel model saving)

```
public function beforeSave()
{
    // $this => the model
    foreach ( $this->toArray() as $name => $value )
    {
         if ( empty( $value ) ) {
                 $this->{$name} = null;
         }
    }
}
```

The problem is when field has a default value defined on database (mysql), for example:

```
$table->integer('value')->default(1);
```

I need to get an array of all nullable or not nullable fields of current model.

How do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Laravel/Eloquent** have no clue about the structure of your database. Assumption is made that whatever operations you implement, database structure is ready for them.

You could query the database to get information about columns. For **MySQL** you'd need to run

```
show columns from <table_name>;
```

This will result in **additional queries** sent to the database.

A **better option**, in my opinion, is to just store such information in model classes, e.g. in

```
protected $notNullable = ['field1', 'field2'];
```

in a similar fashion like **$fillable** or **$guarded** fields are stored. When you write your models you should be aware which columns are `nullable` and which aren't, so it should be the easiest solution.

Comment: Dear down-voters, please leave a comment, I'd love to learn what is wrong with the answer :)

Comment: oh sorry. to solve i just set `protected $notNullables = ['foo', 'bar']` and create the conditions inside the loop. Worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your model or trait

```
use DB;
...
    protected static $_columns_info = NULL;
    protected static $_nullable_fields = NULL;
    public function is_nullable(string $field_name){
        if (is_null(static::$_columns_info) ){
            static::$_columns_info = DB::select('show columns from '.$this->gettable() );
        }
        if (is_null(static::$_nullable_fields) ){
            static::$_nullable_fields = array_map( function ($fld){return $fld->Field;}, array_filter(static::$_columns_info,function($v){return $v->Null=='YES';}));
        }
        return in_array( $field_name, static::$_nullable_fields );
    }
```

and use like

```
app(Model::class)->is_nullable(you_column_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

For PostgreSQL I've updated Sole.dmitry's answer and made a funcion, wich can be performed on a given model. For ex. model User, then on an instance $user->getNullableFields() will return them as an array of the field names that are nullable

```
public function getNullableFields(){

        $columns_info = DB::select("SELECT COLUMN_NAME, IS_NULLABLE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE table_name = '{$this->getTable()}'");

        $nullableFields = array_filter($columns_info, function($v) { return $v->is_nullable == 'YES'; });

        $nullable_fields = json_decode(json_encode($nullableFields), true);

        return array_map(function ($fields) { return $fields['column_name']; }, $nullable_fields);
    }
```